# Composer requrie ext-redis

Tags: php, composer-php, phpredis

I'm trying to set phpredis extension as a requirement for my application. Here is my composer.json:

```
"ext-redis": ">=2.2.7"
```

A've also tried these options: `"^2.2.7"`, `2.2.7@dev`

But all the time I'm getting the error below:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-redis >=2.2.7 has the wrong version (2.2.8-devphp7) installed. Install or enable PHP's redis extension.
```

hy my requirement of `>=2.2.7` doesn't stack with an actual version `2.2.8-devphp7` which seems to fit into this version constraint?

Comment: Try `^2.2.7` instead of `^2.27`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thatwas a typo in my question. Doesn't work.

Comment: I even tried explicitly `2.2.8-devphp7` and composer fails with "Invalid version string". It very much points into a composer issue.

Comment: I filed an [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5264).

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I just did it too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version `2.2.8-devphp7` is simply [not supported and resolves to 0](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5264#issuecomment-215957139):

> We simply cannot parse it. This means that the installed version ends up being unrecognized, and thus it defaults to 0

and will never be supported:

- https://github.com/composer/semver/issues/15
- https://github.com/composer/semver/pull/37

You have to treat that version as a 0 and allow it by the [discouraged](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-are-unbound-version-constraints-a-bad-idea.md) `*` constraint.

---

**Update**: It is now supported since [composer-1.1.1](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/0cca4d1a449527fc0e598fd6519b3a808b1598e2)

Comment: It seems that the issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5264#issuecomment-219495583) and 2.2.8-devphp7 is now considered as 2.2.8